# SFTP Siteground stopped working (org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not determine the type of file)

Tags: phpstorm, sftp

PhpStorm suddenly stopped working, it was working just fine when I was out of town, but now it won't let me connect to SFTP. I double checked that everything was correct: The server, password, SSH key file, username, etc. 
It just stopped working when I got back. I got these logs and they still won't tell me what is wrong. Why can't I log in? I'm using Siteground.

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not determine the type of file "sftp://us###.siteground.us:18765/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:1504)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.isFile(AbstractFileObject.java:1689)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileObject.doListChildrenResolved(SftpFileObject.java:462)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1142)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChild(AbstractFileObject.java:1095)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:192)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:140)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:84)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask.doRun(RemoteHostTask.java:156)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask.run(RemoteHostTask.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://us###.siteground.us:18765/".
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedSftpFileSystem.getChannel(PatchedSftpFileSystem.java:107)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileObject.statSelf(SftpFileObject.java:177)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileObject.doGetType(SftpFileObject.java:112)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:1495)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.intellij.ssh.SshTransportException: Auth fail
    at com.intellij.ssh.impl.SshConnection.a(SshConnection.kt:91)
    at com.intellij.ssh.impl.SshConnection.openChannel(SshConnection.kt:48)
    at com.intellij.ssh.SshConnectionService.sftp(SshConnectionService.kt:170)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedSftpFileSystem.getChannel(PatchedSftpFileSystem.java:57)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.intellij.ssh.SshConnectionUtil.createSshSession(SshConnectionUtil.kt:143)
    at com.intellij.ssh.impl.SshConnection.a(SshConnection.kt:84)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add my IP Address to `Allowed IPs` because I had set up my key while out of town.

I went to `Cpanel` -> `Advanced` -> `SSH/Shell Access` -> `Manage Current Keys` -> `Allowed IPs` and realized I forgot to add my IP Address. I didn't know it at the time that I was setting up my SFTP key.

Could not find this simple tip to check the allowed IPs anywhere in the SiteGround tutorials, google searching, or the log, so thought I'd add this Q&A to stack overflow for anyone else who has this problem.